# How to play local audio with audio_service package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

*I recently discovered [this question](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/354) in the closed issues of the audio_service package. I had the same question so I am reposting it here for visibility.*

The [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) package requires you to pass in a `MediaItem` like so:

```dart
MediaItem(
  id: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3",
  album: "Science Friday",
  title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
  artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5739820),
  artUri: "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg",
)
```

If you want to play a local file, though, there is no clear way to do that. How do you play a local audio file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the package author [here](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/354#issuecomment-641732324):

> This plugin does not play audio.
>
> This plugin only wraps around your existing audio code to allow it to
> work in the background, but it doesn't care how you actually play the
> audio. It's up to you to use other plugins to play the audio. ...
>
> If you look at the example, you'll see it uses the `just_audio` plugin
> to play audio, so a starting point would be for you to consult the
> documentation of that plugin rather than this plugin (which doesn't
> play audio). You will find the answers there.

And [here](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/354#issuecomment-641926102):

> The id is just a unique id for your media item. As per the
> documentation:
>
> ```dart
> /// Metadata about an audio item that can be played, or a folder containing 
> /// audio items. 
> class MediaItem {
>   /// A unique id.   
>   final String id;
> ```
>
> It is not required to be a URL.

So you can just pass in a local path as the `id` and then handle it appropriately by `just_audio` or whatever audio plugin you are using.

```dart
MediaItem(
  id: "assets/audio/my_audio.mp3",
  ...
)
```

In `just_audio` you would use this string with `setAsset()`.