# How to play local audio using just_audio?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, just-audio

I have list of file path like this one: `content://media/external/audio/media/2732` I want to play the audio using the given file path. How can I add that path as a media item?

```dart
MediaItem(
    id: "content://media/external/audio/media/2732",
    title: "Test Song",
)
```

Above code doesn't work.

Finally I found the solution. I used this package: [URI to File](https://pub.dev/packages/uri_to_file).

**Implementation**

```dart
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/2732");
File file = await toFile(uri);
MediaItem(
    id: file.path,
    title: "Test Song",
)
```

Comment: The tag `just_audio` says: "just_audio is a Flutter plugin for playing audio from files, assets, URLs and byte streams."  Because of it being a plugin, you should write some Flutter code to play audio. One example is [How to play a custom sound in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813386/how-to-play-a-custom-sound-in-flutter)

Comment: @Luuk I think you misunderstood, my application is working perfectly in case of audio files fetched from internet. Now I wanted to play the songs those were in my device. I am able to get the list of songs but couldn't make it play.

Comment: see: [How to play local audio with audio_service package in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123009/how-to-play-local-audio-with-audio-service-package-in-flutter)

Comment: That's a demo of network file and asset file not local file but anyway thanks for your support even that didn't help much.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the question is about `content://` scheme URIs. There are two Flutter packages that can help you with that. One is [content_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/content_provider) and another upcoming one is [android_content_provider](https://github.com/nt4f04uNd/android_content_provider) (although this requires the master channel of Flutter).

Comment: Well this package helped me solve the issue: [URI to File](https://pub.dev/packages/uri_to_file).

Comment: Great - if you like, you can also consider writing an answer below and accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I used this package: [URI to File](https://pub.dev/packages/uri_to_file).

**Implementation**

```dart
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/2732");
File file = await toFile(uri);
MediaItem(
    id: file.path,
    title: "Test Song",
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use it like this.

```
Uri.parse('asset:///assets/audios/song.mp3');
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try to add asset:/// in the start of your string.

example :

before : `Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/2732");`

after : `Uri.parse("asset:///media/external/audio/media/2732");`

You can read that if you want : https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/blob/master/just_audio/example/lib/example_playlist.dart